# This is a question about importing texture 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, file-io, textures

Nice to meet you all. Good day.

Please understand that I use a translator because I don't speak English.

What I'm currently trying to do is change the texture3D in the shader to the external texture during runtime using file input/output.

In the case of Texture2D, there is a separate Texture2D.LoadImage(byte[]), but there is no Texture3D.

If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: [`Texture3D.UpdateExternalTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture3D.UpdateExternalTexture.html) ?

Comment: Could you add more details in particular what is your external file exactly? How do you load it into Unity?

Comment: Hello!
What I'm trying to do is utilize assets at these two addresses:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/fo-dicom-60902?locale=en-US
https://github.com/hecomi/UnityDICOMVolumeRendering
Converting DICOM files to texture 2D arrays and turning them into texture 3D files.
After that, during runtime, the purpose is to put the texture 3D file I created into the texture 3D in the shader script using file input/output.

Comment: From your second link: `Convert the imported data to Texture3D in the "Convert" scene.`